# Spectral sequences to involve together two ideals of a ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I'm looking for spectral sequences to involve together two ideals of a ring. For instance, let $I,J$ be two ideals of Noetherian ring $R$ and $M$ be a finite $R$-module then we have the following spectral sequences
$$H_I^i(H^j_J(M))‎\Rightarrow‎ H^{i+j}_{I+J}(M).$$
$$\operatorname{Ext}^i_R(R/I,H^j_J(M))\Rightarrow‎ \operatorname{Ext}^{i+j}_R(R/I,M),\quad \text{if}~~ J\subset I.$$

Comment: What is the purpose of this question?

Comment: I wanna find a relation between $grade(I,M)$ and $grade(J,M)$.

Comment: Why don't you say so in the question? If you eexplain what you want, the chances of gettng what you want are immensely larger!

Comment: @ann: Can you formulate your question in a bit more detail? For instance, let $(R,m)$ be a local (or Cohen-Macaulay) ring, $I = m$, and $M = R$. Then what you are looking for is just grade $J$ which is arbitrary in general. It would be interesting if one can come up with a formula.